# paired turtles moving together netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am creating a model where I have 100 turtles and I have them partnering up. I then would like them to stay in their partnership and to move to any of the random 50 yellow patches I made, only one pair per patch. How would I go about doing this?

The setup code for the patches is:

```
  to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set pcolor 3 ]
  ask n-of 50 patches [ set pcolor yellow ]
 .
 .
 .
 reset-ticks
 end
```

and the code for the partnership is:

```
 to find-partners
 let singles turtles with [partner = nobody]
 if not any? singles [ stop ]

 ask singles  
 [  lt random 50 
 rt random 50
 fd 1 ]

 ask turtles  
 [
 if (partner = nobody) and (any? other turtles-here with [partner = nobody])
 [ set partner one-of other turtles-here with [partner = nobody]

  ask partner [
    set partner myself
]]]
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to give the patches a `patches-own` variable like "occupied?" that is set to "FALSE" during your `setup` procedure. For simplicity, use a `turtles-own` like "nested?" so they can know if they are at their "nest-site." Then when turtles pair off, they can both claim an unoccupied patch as their "nest-site," set it to occupied, and make their way to that patch.

So given that the variables below are properly set in your `setup`:

```
turtles-own [partner nested? nest-site ]
patches-own [occupied?]
```

You can leave your `find-partners` procedure as-is and and a nest-finding procedure. For example:

```
to find-nest
  ask turtles with [ partner != nobody and nested? = false ] [
    if nest-site = nobody [
      set nest-site min-one-of (patches with [pcolor = yellow and occupied? = false]) [distance myself ]
      ask partner [ 
        set nest-site [nest-site] of myself
      ]
      ask nest-site [
        set occupied? true
      ]
    ]
    face nest-site 
    fd 1
    if patch-here = nest-site [
      move-to nest-site
      set nested? true
    ]
  ]
end
```

This code has turtles that have paired off select the nearest unoccupied yellow patch, choose it as their nest, and then make their way towards it in the following ticks.   <sup>[Here](https://lukepc.github.io/nesting_pairs.html)  is the entire simple version.</sup>

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. If anyone is using this for help I highly suggest viewing Luke's provided link.